# How to force flutter `camera` plugin to take photo in portrait mode?

Tags: android, flutter, android-camera

Is there a general way to do this?

To add more context, it seems the camera plugin takes into account the device orientation when capturing image from the camera. Can we control it so that no matter what the orientation is, the result is still the same?

plugin: [camera](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/camera) `0.4.0+3`

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660598/android-camera-preview-orientation-in-portrait-mode) thread?

Comment: @Jaydroid I don't think you can modify the manifest as it's an external "flutter" library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who're struggling with this problem, checking your device orientation when taking photos and its resulting exif data should help. Try these libraries:

[native_device_orientation](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/native_device_orientation)

[exif](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/exif)

[flutter_exif_rotation](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_exif_rotation)

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: Image files captured by most modern devices have EXIF data embedded, which is a  set of metadata like orientation/rotation. Image viewers may or may not take this data into account when showing the image. More [info](https://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html).